# KeyError: 'docSentiment' for sentiment analysis using AlchemyAPI in Python

Tags: python, alchemyapi

I have a text file with userID and tweet text separated by a "-->". I want to load these into a dictionary and then iterate over the values, computing  the sentiment for each tweet using AlchemyAPI. 
My input data is similar to this (real file has millions of records):

```
v2cigs --> New #ecig #regulations in #Texas mean additional shipping charges for residents. https:\/\/t.co\/aN3O5UfGUM #vape #ecigs #vapeon #vaporizer
JessyQuil --> FK SHIPPING I DON'T WANT TO WAIT TO BUY MY VAPE STUFF
thebeeofficial --> #Lancashire welcomes latest #ECIG law READ MORE: https:\/\/t.co\/qv6foghaOL https:\/\/t.co\/vYiTAQ6VED
2br --> #Lancashire welcomes latest #ECIG law READ MORE: https:\/\/t.co\/ghRWTxQy8r https:\/\/t.co\/dKh9TLkNRe
```

My code is:

```
import re
from alchemyapi import AlchemyAPI
alchemyapi = AlchemyAPI()

outputFile = ("intermediate.txt", "w")
tid =  1; #counter for keys in dictionary
tdict = {}  #dictionary to store tweet data
with open("testData.txt", "r") as inputfile :
    for lines in inputfile:
        tweets = lines.split("-->")[1].lstrip()
        tweets = re.sub("[^A-Za-z0-9#\s'.@]+", '', tweets)
        tdict[tid] = tweets.strip("\n")
        tid+=1

for k in tdict:
    response = alchemyapi.sentiment("text", str(tdict[k]))
    sentiment = response["docSentiment"]["type"]
    print sentiment
```

I am getting the error:

```
sentiment = response["docSentiment"]["type"]
KeyError: 'docSentiment'
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Can anybody please help?

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong, but a good place to start would be to print out the contents of `response` to see what you are getting back.  It's possible that the request didn't work for some reason, and the response may contain information on what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the response was successful before trying to access the key.

```
for k in tdict:
    response = alchemyapi.sentiment("text", str(tdict[k]))
    status = response.get('status')
    if status == 'ERROR':
        print(response['statusInfo'])
    else:
        print(response['docSentiment']['type'])
```